# List to Datatable. Datatable doesn't show any values

Tags: c#, winforms, list, datatable

I'm trying to make a "history page". Reading the urls a user have been as a string and adding those to List and transform it to DataTable but when I click on the show History menu option all I get is column "urls" and an empty cell underneath it. I assume I'm probably also using the Add method inappropriately.

Main form class:

```
private void showHistoryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   using (History history = new History())
   {
      history.ShowDialog();
      nonHomepage = URLInput.Text;
      if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(nonHomepage))
      {
         return;
      }
      else
      {
         addToList(nonHomepage);
      }
   }
}

public void addToList(string URLvalue)
{
   listH.Add(URLvalue);
}

public List<string> getList()
{
   return listH;
}
```

History form class:

```
private void History_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form1 br = new Form1();
   list = br.listH;
   DataTable table = ConvertListToDataTable(list);
   dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
}

static DataTable ConvertListToDataTable(List<string> l)
{
   DataTable table = new DataTable();
   //int columns = 0;
   table.Columns.Add("urls");
   foreach(string s in l)
   {
      table.Rows.Add(s);
   }
   return table;
}
```

Any suggestions? What if I put all those urls in the file and then read from a file and write to a textbox/table? Or maybe I should change the data structure? Go for dictionaries, for example? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't debugged this code, I presume. Because I think that the problem is when you pass lists between forms. More specifically, this bit: Form1 br = new Form1();
        list = br.listH;... if you reinstantiate the class, all its variables are set to their default values (and the lists are empty).

Comment: Yeah, it compiles. Shall I just pass the url strings from the main form to History form and make lists in the History form then?

Comment: you should start adding the `Dataset.Extentions` reference so you can use linq directly on the `DataTable` object and transform into a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you create an empty `Form1` in the `private void History_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)` and pass in the `listH` (which is empty) into the method `ConvertListToDataTable(list)`, hence you have empty grid. The solution is you have to change your `History` initialization or explicitly call some method `LoadData` to load the actual list, something like this:

**Solution 1**

```
public partial class History : Form {
  public History(){
    InitializeComponent();
  }
  public Form1 MainForm {get;set;}
  private void History_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {     
    var list = MainForm == null ? new List<string>() : MainForm.listH;
    DataTable table = ConvertListToDataTable(list);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
  }
  //other code ....
}
//Form1 class
private void showHistoryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //note the MainForm initialization using Property initializer
  using (History history = new History {MainForm = this}) {
    history.ShowDialog();
    nonHomepage = URLInput.Text;
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(nonHomepage)) {
      return;
    } else {
      addToList(nonHomepage);
    }
  }
}
```

**Solution 2**

```
//History class
public partial class History : Form {
  //define this method to call explicitly before showing your History dialog
  public void LoadData(List<string> list){
    DataTable table = ConvertListToDataTable(list);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = table;
  }
  //other code ...
}
//Form1 (or Main Form) class
private void showHistoryToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  using (History history = new History()) {
     history.LoadData(listH);// <---- call this first to load data
     history.ShowDialog();
     nonHomepage = URLInput.Text;
     if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(nonHomepage)) {
       return;
     } else {
       addToList(nonHomepage);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @KingKing, it works now but I probably need to save urls into the separate file, so that it remembers the previous session. Do you think it's handy or will it slow down my program? I mean reading and writing from the file all the time.

Comment: @Messerschmitt if the files are not too large, I think it's OK. Even when the file has many many lines, you can always use `threading` to open and load it in background. However I don't think it's your case so we can just load it normally.

Comment: Thanks. One more question (I hope I'm not asking for too many). I wrote some code for event when user double clicks the row with url, so that the url is passed as a string back to the main form and loaded there. However, I got this ArgumentOutOfRangeException when doing this: form.pageInput.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].ToString(); Can't figure out what I'm doing wrong in here. Is it because it's like a collection rather than a string?

Comment: @Messerschmitt `SelectedRows` is **usable** only when you set `SelectionMode` to `FullRowSelect`, otherwise it is always empty **unless** you explicitly select row by clicking on the **row header**.

Comment: I've just checked it, it was initially setted up as **row header**. So I've changed it to **FullRowSelect** and still get the same error. Howeverm if I don't specify index at the end: form.pageInput.Text = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.ToString();    it goes to the method which loads the page and prompts an error there. That means that the string is empty :(

Comment: @Messerschmitt it's hard to diagnose what's going on, you should try posting some new question, anyway this kind of bug is very easy to debug, you have also to be sure that the `dataGridView1` is the one you see on your form.

Answer (score 2):

When you add a table row, you actually have to add a row, not just a string.

```
    foreach(string s in l)
    {
        var row = table.NewRow();
        row[0] = s;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return table;
```

Also, add a breakpoint and make sure your list isn't empty before converting it, and make sure your table is being populated correctly afterwards.

---

Additionally, from an architectural standpoint, if you only have one column of information, you shouldn't really be using a `DataTable`, a `List<T>` will suffice. Is there some reason that you are using a `DataTable` here?

Comment: Actually, he can populate the rows by relying on strings (if the column is of string type, what is the case by default; his DataTable population part is fine).

Comment: I'm new to C# and currently playing around with different data structures to find the one that would suit better and be quiet fast for storing and searching history page. Probably would use the same list for Favourites page. I haven't written any threads yet, so my program is really slow.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative syntax to SpikeX's answer:

```
 int i = 0;
 foreach (string s in l)
 {
      table.Rows.Add()
      tables.Rows[i].SetField("COLUMN NAME", s);
      i++
 }
```

I suppose you only have 1 column in your table, so using SetField might be a bit excessive. But when you have multiple columns it's a bit easier to read, rather than having to go back and check which column has which index.

Comment: What happens when you try either variation?